# Jupyter in VSCodeError: Session cannot generate requests / Kernel died

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm new to VSCode and Python but I am running into these two errors: **Session cannot generate requests / Kernel died**; consistently on various scripts that I try to run in Jupyter notebooks, e.g.:

`librosa.feature.spectral.spectral_centroid(y=sound, sr=sr, n_fft=FRAME_SIZE, hop_length=HOP_SIZE)[0]`
`scipy.fft.fft(sound)`
`autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=1, batch_size=2, shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_test, x_test),)`

(^these are just the lines in the scripts that produce the errors)

So far I've tried:
restarting the kernel, restarting VSCode, restarting PC, changing kernels, updating packages, updating conda, running the code line by line, going through every StackOverflow and other websites looking for possible fix, running it in a .py script, and many others... (also there is no exit() or quit() in the code)

I'm using Python 3.7 and it was all set up through conda.

Please help, this is the 3rd day I'm trying to fix this issue.

Comment: Can these codes be run successfully in the python file? Could you provide a screenshot of the jupyter notebook? And have you tried to install another version of the jupyter notebook?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Since then I reinstalled my entire PC so its difficult to provide any further info or recreate the problem at the moment. But Im wont lock or delete the question yet, in case someone encounters the same problem and finds a solution.